# Referencing Templates in a Bundle

Tags: symfony

I saw in the documentation that reference a template have changed between 3.1 & 3.2

3.1 : `AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig`
3.2 : `@AcmeBlog/Blog/index.html.twig`

Is the 3.1 way is deprecated ? I didn't find anything about it in the upgrades files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old method (with colons) is not officialy deprecated (this will probably change according to Christophe Coevoet's tweet), but is not supported by default in Symfony 4.

So second method (with slashes) should be used for new projects.

According to Mike van Riel's blog you can still enable it in Symfony 4 by installing templating component:

```
$ composer require templating
```

And modify config/packages/framework.yml

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
```

More info at [When your template cannot be found in Symfony 4](http://mikevanriel.com/2018/02/23/when-your-template-cannot-be-found-in-symfony-4/).